# post instlacion ArcSde 10 "error creating Arcsde direct Connection (-9)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, installation

I installed SQL sever 2008'm doing the post installation used ArcSDE 10

these are the steps I am doing in post installation of ArcSDE 10

1. complete installation.
2. SDE Schema.
3. put the name of my server and I connect using windows authentication.
4. put a new password and name of the database "I get message that the database and the password was created successfully" give ok.
5. in the configuration file will leave the default I give next.
6. in the repository setup option I put the name of my instance name of the database you just created together with the password I set when I made the database.

then I get an error message

> connection to "name my base" failed (0) esri server setup utility
>   arcsde date and time
>   -------------------------------------------------- ---------------- Error creating arcsde direct connection (-9)

could someone tell me I'm doing wrong or that I need

Comment: Confused on what you are doing and what you need.  Sde is not required for direct connect.

Comment: Could you please edit the post with actual error messages instead of made up ones?  The changes you made have masked what the error might have been.  You should also explictly state *which* SQL-Server 2008 release (and service pack) you are using, and clarify whether you have installed the terminal service pack (SP5).